# keras multi_gpu_model saved_model failed to load model in TF2 code

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a multi_gpu_model using tensorflow 1.13/1.14 and saved them with keras.model.save('<.hdf5>').
Now, after migrating to tensorflow 2.4.1, in which Keras is integrated as tensorflow.keras, I cannot tensorflow.keras.models.load_model as I did before, due to the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.backend' has no attribute 'slice'
```

After trying to import keras.models.load_model, and trying different versions of keras (2.2.4 -> 2.4.1) and tensorflow (2.2 -> 2.4.1), I cannot load_model from my .hdf5 file using my TF 2.2+ code.

I do know that in TF 2.X + we can train using distributed machines by implementing the "strategy" scope, and it does work, but I have a lot of "old" models that I need to work on the same code base which is now being migrated to TF 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was not the TF versions, but the way I was saving my models on my TF 1.X code versions.

I used the `keras.multi_gpu_model` class for both training and saving, while this practice is wrong, as clearly stated on Keras documentation:

"To save the multi-gpu model, use `.save(fname)` or `.save_weights(fname)`
with the template model (the argument you passed to `multi_gpu_model`),
rather than the model returned by `multi_gpu_model`."

So, after figuring this out a method for model conversion, **using TF 1.X code**, was adopted:

1. build you model from scratch, namely `new_model`
2. load your pre-trained weights from the multi_gpu_model, namely 'old_model'
3. copy your `old_model`'s weights, which is `old_model.layers[3]` (due to the wrong usage of multi_gpu_model) to your `new_model`
4. save `new_model` as .hdf5 file
5. use `new_model`.hdf5 everywhere - TF 1.X and TF 2.X